# CSS: Why "vertical-align: middle" does not work?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Consider the following example: ([live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/cXUnT/))

HTML:

```
<a><img src="http://img.brothersoft.com/icon/softimage/s/smiley.s_challenge-131939.jpeg" /></a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    display: block;
    background: #000;
    line-height: 40px;  
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The output is:

[image]

Why the image is not vertically centered ?

How could I fix that so it will work in all major browsers ?

Please don't assume any image size (like 32x32 in this case), because in the real case the image size is unknown.

Comment: Its working for me in your fiddle (FF 5.0.1 Mac)

Comment: @prodigitalson: I use Firefox 5.0 and it doesn't look perfectly centered. Are you sure that the black areas above and below the image have exactly the same height (should be `(40px - 32px) / 2 = 4px`) ?

Comment: this is bizarre... and i think jsfiddle knows it with a script id of **cXUnT**. btw, doesn't work for me in FF5 Win

Comment: Any way there will be browser issues or else you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/cXUnT/3/

Comment: @misha: Im not sure exactly how much space is there but it looks even between top and bottom... probably about 2px give or take.

Comment: @Beno: Thats odd... if it works for me on Mac and not for you on Win could it be something with the font rendering as it applies to a line-box? @Misha: In your real layout what is the font stack for the `a` look like?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `position:absolute;` for this.

For example:

```
a {
    display: block;
    background: #000;
    line-height: 40px;
    height:80px;
    position:relative;  
}

img {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-16px;
}
```

*NOTE*: This gives `margin-top` half of the image size.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/cXUnT/7/

Comment: I agree with this one. As far as what ive seen, this is best way of doing this without hacking the crap out of IE.

Comment: @Misha Moroshko Right, I had a feeling you might. Theres two viable options: http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html OR you might want to put the images in as CSS `background`'s and use `background-position: center center;`

Comment: yes; that's may be the problem but you can use as background image define  it's background-position:left center ; for vertically center

Answer (score 1):

You should have `display: table-cell` I think, this works only in tables.. I use `line-height` equal to height of the element and it works too.

Comment: not it shoudl work on any `inline` or `inline-block` so long as the line-height is appropriate - which seems to be in this case.

Comment: sorry i overlooked the example... but when i look at it in FF and IE, picture is vertically centered :_)

Comment: you got me at using `line-height` equal to `height`. thanks for the time saver

Answer (score 1):

I can't really tell you the specifics as to why this happens *(I'm curious myself)*. But this works for me:

```
a {
    display: block;
    background: #000;
    line-height: 40px;  
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top:-4px; /* this work for me with any given line-height or img height */
}
```

Comment: This _might_ break in older versions of IE.

Comment: But then again, I couldn't tell you what *might* not (at some point) break in IE (especially IE6 off course ;)

Comment: "..line-height(parent) or img height" thats the point, Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This works for me:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    div.parent {
         position: relative;
    }

    /*vertical middle and horizontal center align*/
    img.child {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="parent">
        <img class="child"> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the vertical size of the element and the line height, then you can vertically center it by using `vertical-align: top` plus a top margin.

For illustration, I created: http://jsfiddle.net/feklee/cXUnT/30/

Answer (score 0):

Just put the img tag inside a div tag the set
    display:table-cell vertical-align: middle to the div. Parent tag should be display:table

Example:

Css

```
a {
 display: table;
 background: #000;
 height:200px;
}
div {
 display:table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML

```
<a>
 <div>
  <img src="http://img.brothersoft.com/icon/softimage/s/smiley.s_challenge-  131939.jpeg" />
 </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Not sure* what's the cause.

**Removing** the `line-height` and **adding** `margins` to the *image* does the trick.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  background: #f00;
}
img {
  margin: .3em auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a>
 <img src="https://placeimg.com/30/30/any">
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using a background image on an `<a>`:

```
<a href="#"></a>    
a {display:block;background:#000;line-height:40px;background:#000 url(http://img.brothersoft.com/icon/softimage/s/smiley.s_challenge-131939.jpeg) no-repeat left center;text-indent:-999px}
```

Comment: I don't want to move the image to background.